# Comparing multiple columns in a table: Regression Testing

Tags: oracle, testing, compare, regression

I am currently performing regression testing and would like to write a query which automatically compares the values in columns between two tables. Hoping to automate this feature in the future too.

Essentially checking each and every cell.

We are currently using an Oracle and MSSQL based environment.

E.G.

```
Table A:

Column 1 |  Column 2 | Column 3
  540        EQUITY    10-09-12

Table B:

Column 1 |  Column 2 | Column 3
  330        CASH      10-03-11
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to compare? All values between column1, 2, and 3 from table A and B?

Comment: This is unclear to me. If you are doing regression testing, does that mean the two tables are produced by two versions of a query (or application, whatever), and you want to check if those two tables are identical? You don't check "each and every cell" (that doesn't actually mean anything); you check to see if the two tables have the same rows, and if duplicates are possible, that both tables have the same number of "copies" of each row. Is that what you need? Easy to do, but please confirm the problem requirement first.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest queries which our testers have found useful for such comparisons is  using the `MINUS` operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   ((SELECT *
         FROM   tableA
         MINUS
         SELECT *
         FROM   tableB)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT *
         FROM   tableB
         MINUS
         SELECT *
         FROM   tableA)) ;
```

This tells you how many rows are in `TableA`,  not in `TableB` and are in `TableB` , not in `TableA`.
This works if both tables have same structure and you are trying to compare only the values.

You can write a dynamic PL/SQL block which checks this count for all tables that you need to compare in a loop and generate a report.

You would also find comparison utilities in `Toad` and `SQL Developer`, which compare table structures as well. For eg:- If columnA is in TableA , missing in TableB etc, you can generate a report.

If the table size is small, you could also make use of external text comparison tools such as *Beyond compare* or *Winmerge*.